# How do I get MKS sed to output this double quote?

Tags: windows-7, cmd, mks

The line

```
echo xxx | sed "s/xxx/a""b/"
```

outputs

```
ab
```

rather than

```
a"b
```

as expected.

What's the fix?

Comment: Use command:
$ echo xxx | sed s/xxx/a\"\"b/
output will be  : a""b

Please note that ("(quote)should be escaped, so we need to do this twice that's the trick here)

Comment: Confirmedhttp://i.imgur.com/l5ZI25f.png . Thanks! Please enter your response as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: can you accepy my answer so it would helpfull for others @Chrissjj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below command: $

`echo xxx | sed s/xxx/a\"\"b/`

output will be : a""b

Please note that ("(quote)should be escaped, so we need to do this twice that's the trick here)